# Is there a way to color in crystal reports?

Tags: c#

Hello guys I thanks you all in advance if you could bring some light with this issue:

I'm trying to generate a report where I may be able to differentiate the text changed from the original text, for example:

Original text: This is the original text
Updated text: this is the **updated** text.

In this example the bold text is supposed to be viewed and printed in a different color, let's say red.

The database is developed in Microsoft SQL server and the front face app in C# with HTML, CSS and javascript.

Comment: What have you tried? Is this conditional formatting? What does google say about this?

Answer (score 0):

Ken Hamady has a recent blog about this scenario.
You can use 3 formulas to split the text into 3 parts: {@Before), {@TargetString}, {@After}.
Place the 3 formulas in a text object (acting as a container) and format {@Target} as you wish.

Ken's approach is to use string location logic. But a simpler approach is to use Split logic. Here is an example, assuming {@TargetString} is a formula holding the target text to be highlighted and {@Notes} is the full text:

{@Before} formula:

```
local stringvar array myArray := Split({@Notes},{@TargetString});
myArray[1];
```

{@After} formula:

```
local stringvar array myArray := Split({@Notes},{@TargetString});
IF UBound(myArray) > 1 Then myArray[2] Else "";
```

[image: Split Logic to Highlight Text in Crystal Report]

There's an alternative solution that can automate highlighting the text in a pdf export from the report using RegEx, wildcard, or target strings logic.

Comment: Thanks @MilletSoftware I've already managed to color in red the new text but  I haven't been able to place it in the final result, maybe because I'm missing the {@TargetString} formula. Could you please share it?

this is what I've been doing:

Comment: Var: Texto
"formación"

Var: Texto_inicio
Instr ({usp_reporte_fichas.actividad_especifica}, {@Texto})

Var: Texto_final
if {@Texto_inicio} = 0
then 1
else {@Texto_inicio} + Length ({@Texto}) -1

Var: Texto_salida_antes
if {@Texto_inicio} <= 1
then ""
else {usp_reporte_fichas.actividad_especifica} [1 to {@Texto_inicio}-1]

Var: Texto_salida_destino
if {@Texto_inicio} = 0
then ""
else {usp_reporte_fichas.actividad_especifica} [{@Texto_inicio} to {@Texto_final}]

Var: Texto_salida_despues
{usp_reporte_fichas.actividad_especifica} [{@Texto_final}+1 to -1]

Comment: Var: Texto_completo
{@Texto_salida_antes}+{@Texto_salida_destino}+{@Texto_salida_despues}

Comment: {@TargetString} is simply the text you are targeting for a different format.

Comment: Thanks again, so how should I reffer to the third formula?

Thank you very much